Is it possible to have multiple long names for the same command-line argument?
Let's show what I mean with an example of a program argument:
-q, --quiet, --silent: Don't show output
I tried to do
#[derive(Parser)]
#[command(version = "0.1.0")]
struct Args {
  // ...
  #[arg(short, long = ["quiet", "silent"], default_value_t = false)]
  quiet: bool,
}

but rust gives me an error because the long argument takes a string, not an array, but is there a workaround using clap to have multiple possible names for the same argument ?

you might be able to do that with an alias: https://docs.rs/clap/latest/clap/struct.Arg.html#method.alias
unfortunately, this probably means you'll have to do it without derive (couldn't find a derive equivalent of the example they show there)

@LielFridman Isn't it possible to use derive for all the other args except this one then ? because being able to use a derive macro like this for parsing arguments is the aspect of this library that I love, and I still want to use it

I believe you can still use the derive (#[arg(..., alias = "silent", ...)]) since they say: "Any Arg method can also be used as an attribute".

@kmdreko your method works, but there is one problem, the alias works but doesn't display on the help message.

@kmdreko after a little bit of searching I found the visible_alias method that adds it to the help message, thank you for pointing me to the right direction

I need to use the alias argument to arg for that (or visible_alias if I want it to display on the help message)
#[arg(short, long, visible_alias = "silent")]
quiet: bool,

